# Auto wire kinesis stream to kinesis firehose?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I'm publishing data to a kinesis stream that is processed by some consumers. I'd like the raw data published to the stream to also be stored in s3. Is it possible to auto wire a kinesis stream to a kinesis firehose or do I need to directly publish to the firehose from a kinesis consumer?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Update@Aug 18, 2017

**Kinesis Firehose can now read data directly from Amazon Kinesis Streams!**

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ann.jspa?annID=4904

---

Before Aug 18,2017

> Is it possible to auto wire a kinesis stream to a kinesis firehose

At the moment, you can't accomplish this, so you have to wire them by yourself.

AWS provides an OSS lambda project to forward Kinesis Streams to Kinesis Firehose.

https://github.com/awslabs/lambda-streams-to-firehose